# Can a whip be used to launch objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation

The inspiration of this question idea is:

- Balearic slingers could potentially have the effectiveness as a bullet and have a range of 400m (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uDtrwNY0Zk&t=290s)
- the theory related to whips that might help.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LPLFCkUH-Y&t=83s)

$$\mathrm{KE}=\dfrac12mv^2$$

If physics is worked out. I think potential applications for the "hill effect" is weaponry (controversial), rocketry or/and energy production. But I will save this paragraph for engineering discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of.

This "Hill Effect" (which is nothing new or discovered by the YouTuber) boils down to:

- Accelerating the whole rope to some kinetic energy with your arm
- Once the end of the rope is in front of you, some kinetic energy will continuously be lost here (since your hand is pulling the rope, thus performing negative work on the rope).
- Some of the kinetic energy energy from the part of the chain closest to your hand is transferred down the chain, towards the end.

The key to note is that the reason this whip seems so vicious and powerful is because (some of) the KE that was once held in the whole chain is now held at the very end of the chain (whose mass is much lighter than the whole chain's).

However, we are not gaining kinetic energy, but instead are gaining speed. Therefore, the final kinetic energy that can be stored at the very end of our chain will never be greater than the initial kinetic energy of the chain.

The benefit of using a chain is that, because of its large mass and how we humans handle it, we are able to give it a lot more kinetic energy than we could give, say, a small ball (we get a lot more time to apply a force by applying it on a chain vs swinging a ball, and a lot more mass to apply that force to).

So, yes, you could technically use this chain to throw projectiles, but your ability to do so is limited by your technique with a chain, which I presume would be rather difficult to master. Instead, throughout history, clever humans came up with different energy-efficient methods for transferring kinetic energy from a massive system to one small component of that system. Examples include the trebuchet, where the whole question is, "how do we get as much of the gravitational potential energy from the load to transfer as KE for the projectile."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you have been really helpful. Even though this is content I already know. Thanks for expanding on those points.